# LWC: change class of lightning-input checkbox depending on status

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, template

I need to give a checkbox a class name depending on whether the checkbox is checked or not.
The checkbox is being displayed inside a lwc template.

How can I achieve this?

```
<template for:each={objInfo.interestList} for:item='interestListItem' class="slds-p-top_medium">
    <lightning-input type="checkbox" 
        value={interestListItem.value} 
        checked={interestListItem.value} 
        class=" ??? "
        onchange={handleInterestChange} >
    </lightning-input>
</template>
```

class=" ??? "  <= should be green or red depending if checked or not

Comment: in your handler you can simply set a attribute with appropriate class and use that in your html as class = {somevar}

Comment: @elijah Comments are not the place for answers.

Comment: @elijah unfortunatly that does not work. Would have been nice and easy, but class remains =>  class="{checkboxStatus}"   when setting is with  this.checkboxStatus="green"

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the value already listed in your data, since LWC doesn't support expressions/calculations within the template, unlike Aura.

```
    class={interestListItem.className}
```

...

As a short example in the controller:

```
objInfo.interestList = [...objInfo.interestList]
  .map((obj) => ({...obj, className: obj.value === 'value1'? 'class1': 'class2' }))
```

Additional work may be necessary. If using a wired method, don't forget to copy the data first:

```
@wire(someMethod, params) wiredHandler({ data, error }) {
  if(data) {
    this.objInfo = {...objInfo}
    this.objInfo.interestList = [...data.interestList].map(/* from above*/)
  }
}
```

Comment: You are a really experienced lwc developer and I am still bloddy beginner trying to make my way through this.... may I ask you what the dots (...) do stand for?

Comment: @JonSnow That's the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). It has several useful features. Here, we use them to copy an array `[...someArray]` and an object `{...someObject}`.

Comment: @jonSnow - everyone is a beginner at some point, as a beginner, it is also your responsibility to be curious, and learn. Trailheads is a great place to start learning, stackexchange is a great place to help you with specific questions related to code (mostly issues). Most of your questions based on your history are 101 modules on Trailhead, I would suggest you take some time to go through them to help you get familiar with LWC and Javascript in general.

Answer (score 1):

As @sfdcfox said, you'll need to compute the class value in the array passed to the iteration template.

Let's imagine that you assign a `red` CSS class to the checkboxes that you want in red.

You then need to use [Styling Hooks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css_custom_properties) to override the [style of the base checkbox](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/checkbox/#Styling-Hooks-Overview).
To do this, add CSS like this to the parent component that holds the checkboxes:

```
.red {
  --sds-c-checkbox-color-border-checked: #990000;
  --sds-c-checkbox-mark-color-foreground: #990000;
}
```

Comment: any idea on how to change disabled checkbox background color?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do this with the styling hooks that are currently exposed.

Comment: Yes, I did looked into documentation but I am having same conclusion, looks like I need to use standard html input only in this case now with customization